# Admin Rights Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

On one of my machines I have Admin Access, although I am not able to see the programs in my uninstall programs section. Which permission is needed for this?

Comment: If you're in the local administrator group, that is pretty much the keys to the kingdom. If your programs aren't showing up in Programs and Features, you might be having a larger issue. Does it show up in any user account?

Comment: The admins on the machine are granted certain privileges. I can install, but not remove. Sometimes I need to remove an old program before installing the updated one, and the view doesn't allow me to see this.

Comment: I think your term for admin, isn't the same as the security group administrator's that I'm talking about. Try this from the command prompt *net user [username] \domain* that should tell you the local groups and the domain groups you are a part of for your login.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that the program you're expecting to see was installed for all users on the machine installation and not for an individual user. Windows Installer maintains a list of installed programs for each user as well as for the machine itself. If someone else installed the program as, say, "Administrator" and you're logged in as "jpavlov" you won't see any programs installed exclusively for "Administrator".

Comment: This makes sense, although the kicker is that once I install the program I am not able to see it right afterwards. It is as that view is shut down to me.